# Why was Maharana Kumbha killed by his own son?

Tags: middle-ages, india, death

Wikipedia asserts:

> Kumbha was killed by his son Udaysimha (Udai Singh I), who thereafter became known as Hatyara (Murderer). Udai himself died in 1473, with the cause of death sometimes being stated as a result of being struck by lightning but more likely to have also been murder.[12] *[Wikipedia:Maharana Kumbha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kumbha_of_Mewar)*

Maharana Kumbha was a great king as he had successfully defended multiple attacks and saved his kingdom; not only that, but his contributions to arts and music are also appreciable. Seeing all these what could have been the reason for his getting killed by his own son? Was it just for the throne or something else was behind the scene?

Comment: [eternalmewar](http://www.eternalmewarblog.com/rulers-of-mewar/maharana-udai-singh-i/)

Comment: @MCW you may want to post that as an answer if that blog is authentic source.

Comment: I lack the skills and background in that region/period to judge whether that is a reliable source. I posted it as a comment in the hopes that it would assist someone else's research.

Comment: Looking at it on WP, I'm getting the vibe I tend to get when decent sources are very sparse (it could also be they are just sparse in English).  Someone who wants to invest some time into looking into this, I'd suggest starting with the sources listed on the WP page,  but don't be shocked if you find not much more is known.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To establish that this isn't a random Wikipedia fail, let's first check the reference, which is [this book](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Asia_and_Oceania/voerPYsAB5wC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA19&printsec=frontcover), *Asia and Oceania:
International Dictionary of Historic Places*. While talking about a building built in Maharana Kumbha's honor, it says:

> **In 1468, Kumbha was assassinated by his son, who became Rana Udai Singh I**. Reviled by all for this patricide, Udai Singh became known as Hatyara (Murderer). Although it is said that he was killed by a flash of lightning in 1473, it seems more likely that Hatyara was struck down by a human hand.

This 1917 book on Kumbha's life offers us many more details, though it's hard to judge its exact reliability. It was written by a judge, though, [Har Bilas Sarda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Har_Bilas_Sarda), so it at least has some credibility.

From Chapter 8, *The Death of Kumbha*:

> It is said that an astrologer had told Kumbhá that he would die by the hand of a Cháran* whereupon the Maharana expelled the whole community from Mewar and confiscated their lands. Prince Rái Mal† befriended them and was involved in their disgrace. He too was banished. A few days before his death, however, the Maharana granted the Chárans permision to return to Mewar.
>
> In A.D. 1468, while Kumbha was one day seated on the edge of a masonry tank, called Mamadeva, near the temple of Kumbhaswami at Kumbhalgarh, which he had built ten years before, his eldest son, Udai Karan, stole up to him and treacherously stabbed him to death.
>
> The motive for this wicked deed might be the fear that Rái Mal might be restored to favour and possibly block the miscreant's way to the throne; or, Kumbhá's enemies, unable to overcome him by force, put up his son to do the wicked deed, promising him assistance to get the throne, as was done in the case of Maharaja Ajit Singh of Marwar in the 18th century, when his son, Abhai Singh, was persuaded to get his father murdered. Udai Karan is known in history as "Udo the Hatiaro."
>
> ---
>
> <sub>*A community whose members write poetry, remain in attendance on Rajputs, and sing their glorious deeds.
>
> †He was the eldest son of Kumbha by his queen Kumbhaldevi</sub>

Really, the likeliest explanation for why Udai Singh killed his father is that he did it to take the throne- I doubt there's anything much more intricate than 'Daddy's king. I wanna be king. I'mma kill Daddy.'